# Converting quicksort function into a class?

Tags: python, arrays, class, quicksort

for part of my homework I need to convert this quicksort code into a class. (I have other sorting algorithms to convert, heapsort,mergesort,bubblesort,etc, but helping with this one example will help me with the others)

Inside the class I need to count the number of array operations performed, and the recursive calls (I assume this would be a counter inside of the init)

I also need to count the number of extra array spaces allocated when performing the algorithm.

I'm not asking to fully finish the class with the above specs completed, all I'm asking is for someone to help me with the creation of the class in order to fulfill the specs, I can figure out where/when to add to the arrayoperations/extra array space counters.

```
from random import * 

def partition(array,first,last) :
    print("first:",first,"last:",last)
    big = first + 1
    small = last
    pivot = array[first]
    while (big <= small) :
        while (big <= last and array[big] <= pivot) :
            big += 1
        while array[small] > pivot :
            small -= 1
        if big < small :
            array[small], array[big] = array[big], array[small]
    array[first], array[small] = array[small], array[first]
    return small

def quickSort(array,first,last) :
    if first >= last :
        return
    pivLoc = partition(array,first,last)

    quickSort(array, first, pivLoc-1)
    quickSort(array, pivLoc+1, last)
    return
```

Comment: If you must have a class, instantiate it and call a method on it that does the work for you. A `QuickSorter` class could have a `sort()` method for example.

Comment: ok @JacobIRR , so for example I would have a "x = QuickSorter()" line, then call x.sort() on it? What would be inside my initializer to satisfy the partition/quicksort function? I'm a beginner programmer by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An arbitrary set of functions can become class methods by enclosing them just like so:

```
class ClassName:
     def __init__(self):
         pass
     ... # Functions go here
```

Of course this is not super useful, but here's how it would look with your code.

```
class QuickSorter:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def partition(array,first,last) :
        print("first:",first,"last:",last)
        big = first + 1
        small = last
        pivot = array[first]
        while (big <= small) :
            while (big <= last and array[big] <= pivot) :
                big += 1
            while array[small] > pivot :
                small -= 1
            if big < small :
                array[small], array[big] = array[big], array[small]
        array[first], array[small] = array[small], array[first]
        return small

    def quickSort(array,first,last) :
        if first >= last :
            return
        pivLoc = partition(array,first,last)

        quickSort(array, first, pivLoc-1)
        quickSort(array, pivLoc+1, last)
        return
```

But you often want some *data members* so your methods can share data. (This is how you track the metrics your professor asked for.)

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = []
    def push(self, new):
        self.array = self.array + [new]
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot! However I should have specified that the arrays I'm using are ctype arrays, and they are created outside of the class! So instead i'll just use counters inside my init to track the metrics, thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped @Fireboy653; if the response addresses your question please mark it as answered